# После переустановки приложения в ios(phonegap) удаляются данные из dataDirectory

Tags: ios, phonegap

Скачивает изображения, складывает в dataDirectory, все нормально до первого обновления приложения. После обновления - данные недоступны. Лицензия Enterprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, в базе нельзя хранить ссылки на файлы в виде: cordova.file.dataDirectory + <имя файла>.

Храним только имя файла. При переустановки iOS меняет путь cordova.file.dataDirectory, и копирует данные из старого.